# PHP Form Validation for a "Company Name" Field Containing periods and dash but not as First and Last Characters

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to validate company names in PHP which should allow, periods, dashes, but not in the first or last part of the name. This is my code

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'. -]+$/", stripslashes($post['company_name']))
```

For now, it allows dashes and perios as first or last character of the company name. I need to DISALLOW periods and dashes as FIRST and LAST characters. How can I achieve this?

Comment: No, just alphanumeric allowed as first and last chars

Comment: ok then `/^[a-z](?:[a-z'. -]*[a-z])?$/i` should work

Comment: can you tell me what difference this is compared to @Nick's answer? I am new to regex and I want to understand more, also, this does not allow if a number is the first and last letters of the name

Answer (score 1):

You just need to force a match to alphabetic characters at the beginning and end of the string:

```php
preg_match("/^[a-z](?:[a-z'. -]*[a-z])?$/i", stripslashes($post['company_name']))
```

This will match an alphabetic character (ensuring the company name starts with one), followed by either

- end of line (this allows us to match a single character name); or
- some number of characters in the set `[a-z'. -]` and an alphabetic character (`[a-z]`) before end of line (this enforces that company names must end with an alpahbetic character)

Note:

- if you use the `i` (case-insensitive) flag to the regex you don't need to specify `A-Z` as well as `a-z`.
- I've assumed you don't want the name to start or end with a single quote either. If you do, change the regex to `^[a-z'](?:[a-z'. -]*[a-z'])?$`

Finally you might want to include digits (`\d` or `0-9`) in the regex's character classes (e.g. `^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9'. -]*[a-z0-9])?$`) as there are many company names (e.g. "F5") that contain them.

Comment: @anubhava I've added a solution for a single character company name

Comment: Technically this won't be a correct answer. What if a company name indeed is of only one character. Also from re-usability point of view to other people, they can't use this regex for such situations. Instead using `^[a-zA-Z']([a-zA-Z'. -]*[a-zA-Z'])?$` solves all problems. Remove single quote from first and last character set if company name can't start/end with single quote

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi you're right, that's a better way to do it and I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nick can you tell me how I can add the digits, I am new to regex and I want to understand the proper way to add these conditions

Comment: nvm I got it! !preg_match("/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9'. -]*[a-z0-9])?$/i", stripslashes($post['signup_name']))

Comment: @SeighthHellsing sorry about the lack of response, been in a meeting. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: actually I just guessed it..well an educated guess I guess. I would still appreciate an explanation about the regex, I am new to regex btw.

Comment: @SeighthHellsing I've added a bit of explanation to the answer, I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer where Alphanumeric can be First and Last, and periods and dashes CANNOT be first and Last

```
!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9'. -]*[a-z0-9])?$/i", stripslashes($post['signup_name']))
```

Thanks for the guys who replied!